# How to model iso-surface of molecular orbitals of singlet and triplet excited states

Tags: organic-chemistry, computational-chemistry, photochemistry, density-functional-theory

I've modelled the iso-surface of the highest occupied molecular orbital of a molecule with DFT in Gaussian.If I were to model the iso-surface of the molecular orbital of the singlet and triplet excited states, how would I do that?Using tdDFT, I've already calculated the excitation energy of both the triplet and singlet manifold.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution using Gaussian?

Comment: Yes, I hope to find results with Gaussian.

Comment: On a research paper, I've read that the Highest Energy Singly Occupied MO (HE-SOMO) is equivalent to the first excited singlet state.  I was wondering why that is the case.

Comment: It is maybe the perfect case when you strictly want to distinguish orbitals and states, and clarify for yourself and for us what exactly you want to visualize.